# What are the SEO benefits of a product specification/detail page vs a product overview page?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, ecommerce, products

Is or should there be a difference between these two pages or should they be combined to form one page? I'm just curious because I haven't seen a product page on an ecommerce site go into heavy detail like what some review sites do.

Lets say I am looking at a Polar watch, on most eCommerce sites there is just a description, with some reviews/comments, but if you go to a site like DC Rainmaker, he dissects that watch and shows everything there is to know about it.

Is this what product pages are supposed to look like, dissected to the finest detail? Or should you have a product page and a review of that product on your blog (given you have an eCommerce store with a blog). Wouldn't this cause duplication?

Comment: Duplication within your own website isn't necessarily bad.  The worst that usually happens is that Google sees that you have the same text on two different pages and decides only to index one of those pages.   See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 3):

This is a question concerning keyword targeting.

If there is traffic on a review keyword specifically, it would be easier to target it with a separate page (no matter if that's a blog post).
That way you can make sure relevancy is high and you can cover the topic to its full extent.

**Remember that you're creating pages for humans and not robots**, therefore, on a product page, you wouldn't include an opinion, a rating etc. whereas on a review page it's something people are looking for.

As for duplication, as long as you're not copy-pasting text, you should be fine. You need to make sure the pages are distinct, and as mentioned above if you correctly use features naturally expected of each page there shouldn't be a problem.

In case you find that there is keyword cannibalization you should correctly [group keywords](https://moz.com/blog/the-advanced-guide-to-keyword-clustering) relevant to each page and optimize the content accordingly. In fact, you might be better off doing this in the first place.

Comment: curious, do you actually go through the whole clustering process?